# htaccess как изменить адреса страниц

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго времени суток друзья!
Есть адрес http://test1.go/index.php?id=46
Как поправить htaccess что бы открывался
http://test1.go/46

??
Подскажите пожалуйста, знаю только как убрать index.php

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот :)

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Не работает, у меня перенаправлен е

Comment: Не работает, у меня перенаправлен с главной страницы на header("Location: /index.php?id=$id_session");

Comment: Так направляйте не на `header("Location: /index.php?id=$id_session")`, а на `header("Location: /$id_session")`. Не вижу проблемы

Comment: Теперь перенаправляет, но страницы сайта не грузятся, перенаправление идёт правильно на адрес http://test1.go/46

Comment: Точно RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=&$1 [L] ???

Comment: @TomasRedl, я изменил ответ, случайно символ ещё один поставил. Смотрите сейчас

Comment: Спасибо тебе!! Всё заработало))

Comment: @Yuri привет! помоги мне тоже, пожалуйста! возьмём его пример. допустим, есть папка  "dice". юзер заходит на http://test1.go/dice, и он видит http://test1.go/index.php?id=dice. как сделать, чтоб RewriteRule не срабатывал, когда там  "dice"?

Comment: @EgorRandomize, это нужно поиграться с регулярными выражениями

Comment: @Yuri я вот нашёл ответ!) условие добавил сверху)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dice

Comment: @EgorRandomize, там недочёт. Если написать `/dice1` то не откроет

Comment: @Yuri а мне так и нужно)

Comment: @EgorRandomize, так надо уточнять, я бы вам это за 2 сек написал как сделать